# Запрет индексации для всех виртуальных поддоменов

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Дано джумла. Материал(статья) на главной, в код статьи через шорткод вставлена загрузка другого модуля, который создает виртуальные города.... матрешка
Не могу убрать из индексации поддомены, сделаные для разных цен в разных городах.
Адреса - поддомен1.сайт.ру, поддомен2.сайт.ру,... поддомен100.сайт.ру.
Как мне убрать из индексации ВСЕ сайты-поддомены. Они виртуальные, на хостинге никаких папок с городами нет, все создано через один модуль, мета-теги тоже прописать не могу, так как одна БД, и все что пишу применимо к основному сайту.
Гуглил, но не нашел прямого ответа, кроме как - 
Цитата:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*google.* [NC]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*yandex.* [NC]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).site.ru.*$ [NC]
>
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.site.ru.*$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^.*$ – [F]

но он не помог.

Редирект не нужен, поддомены остаются, но нужно убрать из поиска.

Подумал еще варианты - мне поможет также запрет индексации абзаца текста статьи или запрет индексации конкретного модуля. Как данный запрет правильно сделать под поисковики?

Comment: вам нужно в каждом поддомейне прописать robots.txt запришающий индексацию

Comment: @L.Vadim "...Они (домены) виртуальные, на хостинге никаких папок с городами нет..." всего один robots.txt и одна бд

Comment: можно тогда сделать так `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

Comment: Снова нет, мета-тег сделает неиндексируемой и страницу поддомена -   поддомен1.сайт.ру/игра и саму основную страницу - сайт.ру/игра.

Comment: Читаю описание к  "<meta name="robots" content="noindex">"  -  
робот не должен ни индексировать документ, ни анализировать стоящие на нем ссылки. 
А можно индексировать документ но не анализировать стоящие на нем ссылки?

Comment: тогда нужно в каждой ссылке прописать `rel=nofollow`

Comment: Тоже так не получилось, все сделано через модуль mycityselector, что генерирует города

Comment: есть еще способ удаление через вебмастер тулс

Comment: Через вебмастер тулс, так просто не удаляет.
Сделал так :  <!--noindex-->сдель код загрузки модуля городов<!--/noindex-->
Но не знаю как проверить, через Screaming frog все на местах.
***********
П.С. Через тег "rel=nofollow" индексирует только главную и все. Или может когда я загрузил на вебмастер карту сайта, можно и так оставить, ведь поиск. роботы еще будут переходить по ссылкам с карты сайта?

Comment: что значит <!--noindex--> ? откуда это?

Comment: https://yandex.ua/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml?lang=ru

Comment: но это не будет работать с гуглом

Comment: Да, вижу, не работает. Глупая ситуация, не выжу виходов.
Дано джумла. Материал(статья) на главной, в код статьи через шорткод вставлена загрузка другого модуля, который создает виртуальные города.... матрешка

Comment: Думаю вопрос с субдоменами можно убрать и просто написать как убрать индексацию всех внешних ссылок.